# Capture of 'params' with non-sendable type 'NSDictionary' in a `@Sendable` closure

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following objective c function where I'm looking to do some async work and call an optional completion block:

```
@objc func setParams(
  _ params: NSDictionary,
  completion: (() -> Void)?
) {
  Task {
    if let params = params as? [String: Any] { // warning here
      await handle(params)
    }
    completion?()
  }
}
```

However, I get the warning:

> Capture of 'params' with non-sendable type 'NSDictionary' in a @Sendable closure

I get that NSDictionary isn't a sendable type but does it actually matter in this instance? What could go wrong here?

Comment: What could go wrong is that `params` could be mutated by another thread, since it is a reference type. You could copy the dictionary  to a swift dictionary outside of the `Task` rather than simply casting the NSDictionary.

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you give an example of that? I've tried but referencing that inside the `Task` then gives me `Reference to captured var 'swiftDictionary' in concurrently-executing code`